# log4j2 asyncLogger does not support Custom Disruptor Queue Full Policy

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

log4j2 Version:2.9.1

When  Disruptor queue is full, log4j2 call Appenders In `CurrentThread` By Default which can result in many Thread blocked in checkrollover or write-file method . To resolve this, I seek to custom the log4j2 AsyncQueueFullPolicy,For Example:if the  `CurrentThread` number is above 100，discard the log

But the only method 
`org.apache.logging.log4j.core.async.AsyncQueueFullPolicy.getRoute(long, Level)` return `Enum` Type `EventRoute`,which only support  `ENQUEUE | SYNCHRONOUS | DISCARD`.In Java,Enum Type Is not supported to be extended.

How can custom AsyncQueueFullPolicy,Please give me an example.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to specify a custom `AsyncQueueFullPolicy`. Your class needs to implement the [AsyncQueueFullPolicy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/AsyncQueueFullPolicy.html) interface, and you [install](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/AsyncQueueFullPolicyFactory.html) it by starting your application with system property `log4j2.AsyncQueueFullPolicy` set to the fully qualified class name of your AsyncQueueFullPolicy implementation class.

When the queue is full, your implementation class will be called *for each event* to decide what to do with the event. Your implementation class will *not* be called if the queue is not full. For each event, your implementation class needs to decide whether to

- DISCARD this event (it will not be logged)
- ENQUEUE this event (this will block until space becomes available in the queue)
- SYNCHRONOUS: bypass the queue and log this event directly to the underlying appender. **Events will appear out of order in the log file if you do this!**

These are the only options that are available to a policy. If you want to propose additional options, please raise a ticket on the [Log4j2 issue tracker](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/LOG4J2).

Perhaps I’m misunderstanding your question, but a custom policy that discards events when the thread id is larger than 100 could look like this:

```
public class CustomQueueFullPolicy extends DefaultAsyncQueueFullPolicy {
    public CustomQueueFullPolicy() {
    }

    @Override
    public EventRoute getRoute(final long backgroundThreadId, final Level level) {
        if (backgroundThreadId > 100) {
            return EventRoute.DISCARD;
        }
        return super.getRoute(backgroundThreadId, level);
    }
}
```

(Be aware that the implementation of Log4j2's `DefaultAsyncQueueFullPolicy` will change with the upcoming Log4j 2.10 release. For more information see [LOG4J2-2031](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2031).)

See also the [DiscardingAsyncQueueFullPolicy](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/xref/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/async/DiscardingAsyncQueueFullPolicy.html) for an example of a policy that discards log events whose level falls below a certain threshold when the queue is full.

Comment: Thanks，i have already commit the [issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2095),hope uncoming version will fix it or offer a bypass solution

Comment: Good, then let’s discuss further on that ticket. Please accept my answer if it was useful to you.

Comment: Does the logging recover once the queue size is available ? 
When I try to do heavy logging through recursion and stop the logging once discard hits,, even after hours, the normal logging does not recover.